# Tower Property for Conditional expectations

Tags: probability

Consider the random experiment in which three fair dice are rolled simultaneously (and independently).

Let $X$ be the random variable defined as the sum of the values of these three dice. 
Let $Y_1$ be the maximum of the three values, let $Y_2$ be their product, and let $Y=Y_1+Y_2$. 
Finally, define $Z$ as the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$, i.e. $$Z=\mathbb{E}[X∣Y].$$

Comment: So what are you asking, how to find $Z$? What are your thoughts? People will give you hints, but please show some effort on the problem.

Comment: So if Z is the E(X|Y) does the tower property hold that E(E(X|Y)|Z) =Z?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is, as you indicated in the comments, if $Z = \mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ then does the tower property hold, implying that
$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left. \mathbb{E}[X|Y] \right| Z \right] = Z?$$

The conclusion you want to draw can be simplified using the definition of $Z$ to $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z=z] = z$, which is true, and does not rely on the Tower Law. If you condition any random variable on its own value, the result is deterministic, since you took all the stochasticity out in the conditioning. In other words, $\mathbb{E}[A|A=a] = a$ whatever $A$ is, as long as the expectation on the left-hand side is defined.

Comment: But since Y=the maximum + their product, how can you find E(X|Y)?

Comment: @user130272 why would you need to? If the only thing you are asking about is whether $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z=z]=z$, this is trivially true for any random variable - you are conditioning it on its own value, it becomes a constant.

Comment: So, how would I go about finding the value of Y if all we know is that it is the sum of the product and maximum?

Comment: @user130272 I don't understand. What exactly is the question you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm just confused about how to find what the constant would be